# Get all 2 columns sum of multiplication result using sql query

Tags: mysql

I have following column in MySQL database table:

```
noOfChild    noOfAdult    childPrice    adultPrice
==================================================
1            1            120           174  
3            2            14            47
4            3            45            49
```

Now, I want to get sum of all `noOfChild` * `childPrice` and `noOfAdult` * `adultPrice`.

For that, I am using this query but it's showing only first row result not all rows. How can I get it?

```
$account->rowQuery("SELECT (noOfChild * childPrice) AS totalChildPrice, 
(noOfAdult * adultPrice) AS totalAdultPrice FROM booking ");
```

Result should be this:

```
1 X 120 = 120
3 X 14  =  52
4 X 45  = 180
         =====  
          352 for child
```

and

```
1 X 174 = 174
2 X 47  =  74
3 X 49  = 147
         =====  
          395 for adult
```

Comment: This is a poorly designed table.

Comment: why? the actual table has few more columns. I just showing here 4 columns only.

Comment: Your query doesn't call `sum()`.

Comment: @revo should I use sum() like this: `AS SUM(totalChildPrice)` ?

Comment: No it should be `SELECT SUM(noOfChild * childPrice) AS totalChildPrice, 
SUM(noOfAdult * adultPrice) as ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$account->rowQuery("SELECT (noOfChild * childPrice) AS totalChildPrice, 
(noOfAdult * adultPrice) AS totalAdultPrice, 
SUM(noOfChild * childPrice) AS sumForChild, 
SUM(noOfAdult * adultPrice) AS sumForAdult 
FROM booking ");
```

Comment: can I get the total of `sumForChild` and `sumForAdult` ?

Comment: like `SUM(sumForChild) + SUM(sumForAdult)` ?

Comment: i have added that

Comment: query is not running.  Showing: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Comment: without `(sumForChild + sumForAdult) AS Total ` this line query is okay.

Answer (score 0):

A more normalised design *might* look like this:

```
order_detail
order_id category  quantity price
     101 child            1   120
     101 adult            1   174
     102 child            3   14
     102 adult            2   47
     103 child            4   45
     103 adult            3   49
```

Then the query becomes trivial...

```
SELECT category, SUM(quanity * price) FROM order_detail GROUP BY category;
```